# how to do beanutils converter for arraylist to double array

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to reconstruct a bean using BeanUtils.  The BeanUtils.populate(obj,map) is almost exactly what I need except I think I need a converter as one of the things in the map is an arraylist but the bean needs an array[].  I have tried to write a converter for it but it doesn't go into the convert method.  Calling populate gives IllegalArgumentException with message 'argument type mismatch'
Bean code:

```
public class TestObject implements Serializable 
{
    private double[] data;

    public double[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(double[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Application Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ConvertUtils.register(new DoubleArrayConverter(), double[].class);
    Map<String, Object> result = getMap();
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.test.TestObject");
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
    BeanUtils.populate(obj, result);
}
```

Converter code:

```
public class DoubleArrayConverter implements Converter 
{
    //takes in an arraylist and returns a double[]
    public Object convert(Class arg0, Object arg1) 
    {
        ArrayList list = (ArrayList)arg1;
        double[] data = Doubles.toArray(list);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the Google library that includes Doubles

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Doubles;
```

and setting some values into the map

```
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();
    listDouble.add(123.45);
    listDouble.add(678.90);
    result.put("data", listDouble);
```

I was able to run your code and populate the bean. It is important that the map key 'data' agrees with the setData and getData methods.

Are you sure your Map has an array list in it?